# Set a minimum and maximum for custom multifield elements in CQ5?

Tags: javascript, aem, day-cq

I'm currently working on a AEM component that include custom multiefield and I have faced a problem I don't know how to solve it.
I have created a custom widget for this which allows to include multiefield in multiefield. From the documentation read, as I understood there's no default configuration to this for widgets API config.

My dialog nodes:

```
<questions
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    xtype="panel"
    title="Questions">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <quiz-data
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                fieldDescription="Click the '+' to add a new data"
                fieldLabel="Quiz"
                name="./quizData"
                xtype="multifield">
            <fieldConfig
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    xtype="apps.mypath.widgets.MultieField"/>
        </quiz-data>
    </items>
</questions>
```

The widget is working fine, except I want to set a minimum required multiefields and a maximum. I have found on the web a example, but I don't really understand how to do it, take a look at the code bellow:

```
myNamespace = {};
myNamespace.myCustomFunction = function (dialog) {
    var isValid = function () {
        var valStatus = true;
        ... custom JavaScript/jQuery to check if 3 items exist ...
        return valStatus;
    };
    if (!isValid()) {
        CQ.Ext.Msg.show({title: 'Validation Error', msg: 'Must contain at least 3 items!', buttons: CQ.Ext.MessageBox.OK, icon: CQ.Ext.MessageBox.ERROR});
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Would be great, if someone can explain how can I achieve this for my custom multiefield, or any other ideas? Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018858/how-to-limit-the-number-of-elements-in-multifield-in-cq5?rq=1 ?  Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736103/set-a-minimum-limit-in-a-custom-multifield-component?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement JavaScript in the Classic UI you will use Listeners. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"
          xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
          height="600"
          width="600"
          title="My Component"
          xtype="dialog">
    <listeners
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        beforesubmit="function(dialog){ return myNamespace.myCustomFunction(dialog); }"/>
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:TabPanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

All the listeners available to you are listed in the [CQ Widgets API documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html). For example, if you look at the [Dialog API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Dialog) you will see all the Public Events.

I can't comment on your custom widget, however this JavaScript example when used in conjunction with the dialog listener above, will validate all your multifields with custom properties of `maxLimit` and `minLimit`.

The dialog:

```
<quiz-data
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldDescription="Click the '+' to add a new data"
    fieldLabel="Quiz"
    name="./quizData"
    minLimit="2"
    maxLimit="4"
    xtype="multifield">
    <fieldConfig
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="textfield"/>
</quiz-data>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};

myNamespace.myCustomFunction(dialog){
  var multifields
      field,
      max,
      min,
      length,
      x;

  multifields = dialog.findByType('multifield');

  for (x = 0; x < multifields.length; x++) {

    field = multifields[x];
    max = parseInt(field.maxLimit, 10);
    min = parseInt(field.minLimit, 10);
    length = field.getValue().length;

    if (max && length > max) {
      CQ.Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Validation Error',
        msg: field.fieldLabel + ' must have no more than ' + max + ' items.',
        buttons: CQ.Ext.MessageBox.OK, icon: CQ.Ext.MessageBox.ERROR});
      return false;
    } else if (min && length < min) {
      CQ.Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Validation Error',
        msg: field.fieldLabel + ' must have at least ' + min + ' items.',
        buttons: CQ.Ext.MessageBox.OK, icon: CQ.Ext.MessageBox.ERROR});
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```